# Django admin - dynamic way of defining list_editable

Tags: django-admin

My goal is to make some fields editable in the list view. But the problem is that the fields are determined dynamically using `get_list_display`. Moveover, I would like to define the elements of the `list_editable` to be dynamic as well. However, Django does not seem to provide any method like `get_editable_list`. Is it made deliberately ? How can this be achieved ?

Now my code looks like this:

class MyModelAmdin(admin.ModelAdmin):

```
list_editable = ('field1')
# change_list_template = "files_changelist.html"

def get_list_display(self, request):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        list_display = ('field1', 'field2',)
    else:
        list_display = ('field1',)
    return list_display
```

Django (justfully) complains that some of the fields which are not included in the `list_display` are included in the `list_editable`. Any way ouy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question!! Required a bit of digging in the code, but...

> Django does not seem to provide any method like get_editable_list

Yes, this is correct. Django doesn't provide any built in method to do this.

> Is it made deliberately ?

I'm not sure, it could be an oversight, but I suspect not. The check that makes sure there is nothing in `list_editable` that isn't in `list_display` is run right at the beginning when django starts up, you can't even `runserver` with this condition. The fact that it is checked in this way, rather than just raising a normal error, makes me think there is good reason to make absolutely certain this condition is held. Adding a dynamic way to set `list_editable` would make such a check impossible.

> How can this be achieved ?

There are a few methods inside `ModelAdmin` which use `self.list_editable`. You could reimplement them to use your own `self.get_list_editable(request)` method. I think the easiest way however would be to overwrite `changelist_view` and set `list_editable` before anything else, then all the other methods will be using the correct `list_editable` e.g:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.modelAdmin):
    list_editable=()  # so the check passes - or can just omit this line completely

    def get_list_editable(self, request):
        # whatever you want here

    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        self.list_editable = self.get_list_editable(request)
        return super().changelist_view(request, extra_context)
```

Just test thoroughly and make 100% sure that your `get_list_editable` and `get_list_display` methods won't lead to a situation where you have something in `list_editable` that is not in `list_display`.